# Symfony2 built-in server, how to open .pdf file in browser window

Tags: symfony, firefox, pdf

I am developing a (very simple) Symfony2 web app which has a show view with a link to a .pdf file. 
If I test it by the built-in web server, say at localhost:8080, I am not able to open the .pdf file within a browser window. I just get a download pop-up:

[image: download pop-up]

I am using Firefox, which works fine with .pdf files otherwise. Also, if I move exactly the same Symfony app within a real web server (Apache), .pdf links open within a browser window.

So it seems to be an issue (missing feature) with the built-in web server, is it? Question: is there a way to fix it?

EDIT My controller to produce a list of .pdf files

```
/**
 * Show test pdf   
 *
 * 
 * @Route("/showpdf", name="Myname_Evento_showpdf")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Template()
 */
public function showpdfAction()
{

$finder = new Finder();
$iterator = $finder->files()->in('bundles/Mynameblog/pdf/');

 $response = new Response();
 $pdfFilename='006.pdf';
 $response = $this->render('MynameBlogBundle:Evento:showpdf.html.twig', array('pdf'=>$pdfFilename, 'pdfs'=>$iterator));

 return $response;
}
```

Fragment of my showpdf view template

```
    {{ pdf }}
    {% for entity in pdfs %}
        <tr>

            <td><a  href="{{ asset('bundles/mynameblog/pdf/') }}{{ entity.FileName }}">{{ entity.FileName }}</a></td> <br>

        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```